# Transforming an R Dataframe with 2 columns and delimiter in rows

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, split, transformation

I have a dataframe that has two columns "id" and "detail" (df_current below). I need to group the dataframe by id, and spread the file so that the columns become "Interface1", "Interface2", etc. and the contents under the interface columns are the immediate values under each time the interface value appears. Essentially the "!" is working as a separator, but it is not needed in the output.

The desired output is shown below as: "df_needed_from_current".

I have tried multiple approaches (group_by, spread, reshape, dcast etc.), but can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sample Current Dataframe (code to create under):

| id | detail |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ! |
| 1 | Interface1 |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | ! |
| 1 | Interface2 |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | ! |
| 2 | Interface1 |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | ! |
| 2 | Interface2 |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | ! |
| 3 | Interface1 |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 3 | d |

```
df_current <- data.frame(
        id = c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2",
               "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3",
               "3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4",
               "4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4",
               "5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5",
               "5","5","5","5"),
        detail = c("!", "Interface1","a","b","!",
                   "Interface2","a","b","!","Interface1",
                   "a","b","c","!","Interface2","a",
                   "!", "Interface1","a","b","c","d",
                   "!", "Interface1","a","b","!",
                   "Interface2","a","b","c","!","Interface3",
                   "a","b","c","!","Interface1","a","b","!",
                   "Interface2","a","b","c","!","Interface3",
                   "a","b"))
```

Dataframe Needed (code to create under):

| ID | Interface1 | Interface2 | Interface3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | NA |
| 1 | b | b | NA |
| 2 | a | a | NA |
| 2 | b | NA | NA |
| 2 | c | NA | NA |
| 3 | a | NA | NA |
| 3 | b | NA | NA |
| 3 | c | NA | NA |
| 3 | d | NA | NA |

```
df_needed_from_current <- data.frame(
        id = c("1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","5","5","5"),
        Interface1 = c("a","b","a","b","c","a","b","c","d","a","b","NA","a","b","NA"),
        Interface2 = c("a","b","a","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
        Interface3 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","a","b","c","a","b","NA")
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We remove the rows where the 'detail' values is `"!"`, then create a new column 'interface' with only values that have prefix 'Interface' from 'detail', use `fill` from `tidyr` to fill the `NA` elements with the previous non-NA, `filter` the rows where the 'detail' values are not the same as 'interface' column, create a row sequence id with `rowid`(from `data.table`) and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df_current %>%
   filter(detail != "!") %>%
   mutate(interface = case_when(str_detect(detail, 'Interface') ~ detail)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   fill(interface) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   filter(detail != interface) %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(id, interface)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = interface, values_from = detail) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
#   id    Interface1 Interface2 Interface3
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 1     a          a          <NA>      
# 2 1     b          b          <NA>      
# 3 2     a          a          <NA>      
# 4 2     b          <NA>       <NA>      
# 5 2     c          <NA>       <NA>      
# 6 3     a          <NA>       <NA>      
# 7 3     b          <NA>       <NA>      
# 8 3     c          <NA>       <NA>      
# 9 3     d          <NA>       <NA>      
#10 4     a          a          a         
#11 4     b          b          b         
#12 4     <NA>       c          c         
#13 5     a          a          a         
#14 5     b          b          b         
#15 5     <NA>       c          <NA>
```